# What's the notation for writing a number as its digits

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, notation, decimal-expansion, number-systems

Hoping this is a simple question, I'm pretty certain this is covered in number theory, but I haven't had much time to pour through my number theory book. I'm wondering what the notation for writing an integer as its digits is.

For example, given $435$ is it something like $4|3|5$?

Thanks

Comment: I would say $435$ is writing $435$ 'as its digits'

Comment: [I've seen $(435)_{10}$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix)

Comment: If you added something, such as the bars, what value would they have? What extra purpose would they communicate beyond just writing the number?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery To express things like the sum of a number's digits, product, etc.

Comment: Ah, so perhaps you're more interested in the symbolic case? Such as a way to write $a \cdot 10^2 + b \cdot 10 + c$ where $a, b, c \in \{0, \dots, 9\}$?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery That sounds like what i'm looking for, could you perhaps elaborate a little?

Comment: Sometimes you might write $d_nd_{n-1}...d_0$, say $435 = d_2d_1d_0$, $d_2 = 4, d_1 = 3, d_0 = 5$. Perhaps that's what you mean?

Comment: @Countingstuff Thank you! That looks about right!

Comment: "pore" not "pour"

Comment: I don't think there is any standard.  Whatever you do, define and state what you are doing.  It's enough to say, "let's write $a_na_{n-1}..a_1a_0$ to be the expression if the number in terms of its digits".  Others prefer $a_n.a_{n-1}.....a_1.a_0$ as the "$.$" can resemble the standard of concatination.  But it doesn't matter your notation as long as you specify what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like $\overline{ABCD}$ as a shorthand for $1000A+100B+10C+D$. I see this notation used sometimes in problems dealing with a number's digits.

Answer (score 1):

I always used

$$[a,b,c,\dots,z]_B$$

where $a,b,c,\dots,z$ are base-$10$ numbersto represent a number in base $B$. The advantage is that $a,b,c, \dots$ don't have to be single-digit integers.

For example, $[10, 9, 8]_{16} = 10\cdot 16^2 + 9 \cdot 16 + 8$. If it is clear what I'm doing, I don't use the brackets when doing arithmetic in base $B$.

For example, to compute $3 \times [10, 9, 8]_{16}$:

\begin{array}{c}
         & 10 &  9 &  8 \\
  \times &    &    &  3 \\
      -- & -- & -- & -- \\
         & 30 & 27 & 24 \\
\end{array}

and $[30, 27, 24]_{16} = [30, 28, 8]_{16} = [31, 12, 8]_{16} = [15, 1, 12, 8]_{16}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something, just do it.

Say:  For purpose of notation am going to indicate a number use expression seperated by $|$ to mean an integer whose digits are the values between bars.  What I mean for example $|a|9-a|2$ will mean a three digit number where the first digit is $a$, the second $9-a$, and the third digit is $2$.  i.e. $a|9-a|2 = a*10^2 + (9-a)*10 + 2$.

It doesn't matter if there is or isn't any standard notation (there isn't).  You have expressed what you intend.